# Getting the GPU connection type in Windows XP?

Tags: c++, windows, gpu

I need to detect in code (C++) how the graphics card is connected to the monitor/s, i.e. vga or dvi etc.

I found two ways that I could do this:

- by querying the Windows Management Instrumentation for [D3DKMDT_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546605.aspx) or
- using the nVidia API function NvAPI_DISP_GetMonitorCapabilities,

but both of these are only supported in Windows Vista or higher.

There must surely be a way of doing this in XP, but after much searching I just can't find one and it's becoming quite urgent that I find a way.

Any ideas?

Comment: _There must surely be a way of doing this in XP_

Must there? It seems plausible to me that there is not.

Comment: Judging from the amount of attention this question has received I tend to agree, it does seem quite strange to me that those 2 functions would be introduced in Vista onwards unless there was a need for them, though. So if there was a real need you'd think that it would be fulfilled by the time XP came out.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you want to know, though. It doesn't seem at all useful. Knowing if the connection supports HDCP might have some value, but that's independent of the actual interface being used.

Comment: @BillWalton: but if there was a way to do it in XP, why would anyone bother introducing *new* functions to do it in Vista? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you can use `EnumDisplayDevices` ([link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and parse some informations as described [here](http://www.windows-api.com/microsoft/Win32-GDI/31775521/determining-physical-vgadvi-port-a-monitor-is-connected-to.aspx). It's basically about matching physical displays with logical ones.

Comment: Hi macs, 

Thanks for the reply. Apologies if I was not clear enough with my question but what I want is not to know which port on the graphics card a monitor is connected to, but specifically what type of port on the graphics card the monitor is connected to, as the piece of software I'm working on needs to run on many different graphics cards which may have vga, dvi, or hdmi output. Is it possible to get this information from  DISPLAY_DEVICE struct too?

Thanks.

Comment: I would say that this is possible, you just have to identify the port type, which should also be possible (but right now i don't know how, maybe google will help out).